# Compute Infinite sum of Zero Order modified Bessel Function with COS

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am looking for the close integral series expression of following Modified Bessel Function.
$T(r,z)=\sum_{i=0}^n[C_1I_0(\lambda_nr)+C_2K_0(\lambda_nr)]cos(\lambda_nz)$

I didn't find a closed expression for this quantity in the literature right now. Could anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: in which $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constant coefficients.:)

Comment: What are $\lambda_n$?

Comment: This is the general solution of a partial differential equation, and $\lambda_n$ can be seen as a series with constant values.

Comment: There's no closed form then

Comment: Also your title says "infinite", but your expression is a finite sum. Which is it?

Comment: Note that the infinite series might very well diverge, depending on the sequence $\lambda_n$ and whether it grows or not